# IIS Express (Debug Mode) and HTTPS

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting

I was trying to enable HTTPS on my production website and accidentally put the configuration:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="(.*)" /> 
        <conditions> 
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
      </rule>   
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

into `Web.config` instead of `Web.Release.config`

Ever since, my IIS Express goes to HTTPS.

I cannot make it stop doing this ... just want IIS Express to go to HTTP.

1. Backed out the change.
2. Did a solution clean/build.
3. Manually wiped out `\bin` and `\obj`
4. Rebooted Visual Studio .NET
5. Searched `C:\Program Files\IIS Express` for anything relating to HTTPS
6. Searched `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress` for anything related to HTTPS

No success.

Any thoughts on how I can make it go back to HTTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try empty the browser cache, storage etc.

Check out the projects properties:

[image]

Or completely disable SSL for the project:

[image]

Comment: Those are some great tips, thank you!  I'm going to check them out now.

Comment: Sorry ... how do I get into the 2nd dialog window you show with "Development Server" and "SSL Enabled"?

Comment: Second dialog: click on the project in the solution explorer and open the Properties window.